# How to insert text in bitmap with mvvcross/monodroid?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, image, mvvmcross

I'm would like to insert a string text in bitmap picture. I have to use mvvmcross/monodroid to create an application, so I can't use [Graphics object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) or monodroid specific language (the code have to run on android/wp8/winRT...). 
Do you know any libraries that can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating graphics is not portable functionality - it's normally best to do this using platform specific code which often gets backing from hardware acceleration.

I believe the correct way to handle this is to inject a specific implementation on each platform. I've done this myself on a customer project - but that's their IP - not open source code.

One library that may help unify your code is CrossGraphics - https://github.com/praeclarum/CrossGraphics - but this is still native code on each platform.